# link a value from an array to another in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying two combine two arrays based on the values names.

Here what I'm trying to do :

```
$array1 = ("fifa21","pes21","halflife2","carma2");
$array2 = ("fifa21_cover","pes21_cover","halflife2_cover");
```

I want to loop through both arrays and if value from array1 match value from array 2 it will list both values like this :

```
fifa21  - fifa21_cover
pes21   - pes21_cover
halflife2 - halflife2_cover
carma2 - default_cover
```

if not find anything in the array2, a default cover will be used.

Note: the arrays will be filled dynamically based in a scanDir (two different folders search) and the arrays can be sorted differently than shown in the example above.

Comment: I see you want to display a default value if array1 doesn't match any value in array2, but what happens if a value in array2 doesn't match any value in array1?

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will loop through array1 and check to see if the item cover exists in array2, if it does then it will echo out in the format you wanted.

```
    $array1 = array("fifa21","pes21","halflife2","carma2");
    $array2 = array("fifa21_cover","pes21_cover","halflife2_cover");

    foreach ($array1 as $item) {
      if (in_array($item."_cover", $array2)) {
        echo "<p>".$item." - ".$item."_cover</p>\n";
      } else {
        // use default cover...
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. I’ve just figured it out by comparing both arrays using a foreach to array1 and a foreach to the array2 inside the first foreach then I check if the value from array2 match the value from array1, if so I add it to a MySQL db else I add the value from array1 to the db but with the default cover. I then get the values from the dB and print them to an html table. I will try your method to check the differences. ;)

Answer (score 0):

*(because it is lunch time and I need to write some code)*

Given two arrays:

```php
$array1 = ["fifa21", "pes21", "halflife2", "carma2"];
$array2 = ["fifa21_cover", "pes21_cover", "halflife2_cover"];
```

A function such as this can walk through and look for items that start with those values:

```php
function merge_arrays(array $array1, array $array2): array
{
    $output = [];

    array_walk(
        $array1,
        static function ($key) use ($array2, &$output) {

            $items = array_filter($array2, static fn($f) => 0 === mb_strpos($f, $key));

            if (count($items) === 1) {
                $output[$key] = reset($items);
                return;
            }

            if (count($items) === 0) {
                $output[$key] = 'default_cover';
                return;
            }

            throw new RuntimeException('More than one item found starting with key ' . $key);
        }
    );

    return $output;
}
```

When called as:

```php
print_r(merge_arrays($array1, $array2));
```

It will output:

```
(
    [fifa21] => fifa21_cover
    [pes21] => pes21_cover
    [halflife2] => halflife2_cover
    [carma2] => default_cover
)
```

For your use-case, it might be overly complicated when compared to a `for` loop, but it does the job.

Another version that more-blindly assumes only a one-to-one match could use the `??` operator for a null check, although I wouldn't recommend this. The more terse and compact that code looks, the more I find that it is usually very hard to reason about, especially in the future:

```php
function merge_arrays(array $array1, array $array2): array
{
    $output = [];

    array_walk(
        $array1,
        static function ($key) use ($array2, &$output) {
            $output[$key] = array_filter($array2, static fn($f) => 0 === mb_strpos($f, $key))[0] ?? 'default_cover';
        }
    );

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All code snipping provided works, however if the array values have extension it always assumes the default cover. I can figure it how using my code by removing the extension for compare purpose, and then I add it back.

Inside my loop I use this :

```
$keyvaluetemp = substr($keyvalue, 0, strrpos($keyvalue, "."));
```

the above it inside my first ForEach (where I check the first array), and then in the covers array I remove the "_cover" by nothing :

```
$keyvalue2temp = (str_replace("_cover", "",$keyvalue2));
```

then I use the following code inside the second ForEach to add the data to a DB:

```
// if fantart match the game file name so we associate it to the game and save to the DB

if ( stripos ( $keyvalue2temp , $keyvaluetemp ) !== FALSE )
{                           
    $sql = "UPDATE listgames SET FanArt='$keyvalue2' WHERE Name='$keyvalue'";
    $con->exec($sql);
}
                        
// if fanart is empty we add a default picture
$checkifempty = "SELECT `FanArt` FROM `listgames` WHERE `Name` = '$keyvalue'";
$runsql = $con->query($checkifempty);
$row = $runsql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$fanartkey = $row['FanArt'];

if($fanartkey == '')
{
    $sql = "UPDATE listgames SET FanArt='nopic.JPG' WHERE Name='$keyvalue'";                            
    $con->exec($sql);
}
```

Later in my code I print the results from the DB. I don't know if this is the best approach, however it does exactly what I want :)

Comment: Did you realize that your question's [mcve] over-simplified the sample data?